# Importing blender rig into Cinema 4D Lite

Tags: animation, objects, export, rigging, armature

I'm new here, so please forgive me if I break a rule. I am a cinema and animation student creating an animated film that combines 2D and CGI animation. For compositing and other reasons, I would like to take CGI characters that I have already modeled and rigged in blender and import them into After Effect's Cinema 4D Lite, where I will animate and render them.

I tried converting a rigged model to a .OBJ file and importing it into Cinema 4D Lite (within After Effects). I was able to get the model in, but the rig does not seem to have followed. I can't see it in the viewer window or in the list of imported objects. Is there something I need to do on blender or Cinema 4D's side to make this work? Is this even possible in my version of C4D? Any and all advice is greatly appreciated. (Except for animating in blender and then just exporting the animation to C4D- that's a last resort I'd like to avoid if possible.)

I will be cross-posting this question to other blender and Cinema 4D forums; if this is disallowed, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think obj supports rigs. Try fbx.

Comment: The obj specification does not support skeletal animations. You could try to export as fbx or collada. See [http://www.maxon.net/..](http://www.maxon.net/fileadmin/maxon/products/cineware/CINEWARE_Comparsion_Chart.pdf) for supported imports.

Comment: Yep, Collada should work. At least, worked for me :)

Comment: Obj does not support rigs for blender imports